# How to display user log in information at the corner of the page using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, logout

I created a web page that the user needs to log in. I want the user to see his/her information. That says hello **user1** and click here to logout. Here my code, I can't even see the logout button.

update: I see the username that I did not log in with that username.  I entered the website with the username student. But it shows a different username. See the picture below.[it supposed to write welcome student not yasemin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4LO9.png)

login code :

```
// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");


    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");

    }


    if (count($errors) == 0) {

        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);


        if('student' == $row['user_type']) {
                 header('Location: ogrenciarayuzu.php');
                 exit();
    } elseif ('department' == $row['user_type']) {
                 header('Location: bolumsekreterligiarayuzu.php');
                 exit();

    } elseif ('institute' == $row['user_type']) {
                 header('Location: enstituarayuzu.php');
                 exit();    

    } 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
        }

     }

     ?>
```

I put this code where I want to see the login information.

```
  <?php session_start(); ?> // at the beginning of my code

   .
   .
   .
    <?php  
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) :
    ?>
    <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
    <p ><a href="index.php" style="color: black;"> <input type="submit" value="Logout" name="logout" 
    class="button"/></a>  </p>

      <?php endif ?>
```

To make it log out successful, I put this code in my `index.php` file

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
header("location: login1.php");
 }
 ?>
```

Please help me why I can't still see. What is the problem here?

Comment: what you exactly want to do here

Comment: I want to see the username when the user logged in the website.

Comment: are you setting the session when user login to their account

Comment: post your login code as well

Comment: Where else should I put session_start() code

Comment: I put session_start(); for each page

Comment: do you have duplicate username and password in the database?

Comment: No,  the username displayed on the secreen was in my previous database, I deleted it and I created new one and there is no such  user in new one.

Comment: yeah i found an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error in your code, your code failed to set the session, when the
>   condition found true, then it redirect user to another .php page as
>   per the condition which you have used.

Try this code.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

    if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

        if (empty($username)) {
            array_push($errors, "Username is required");


        }
        if (empty($password)) {
            array_push($errors, "Password is required");

        }


        if (count($errors) == 0) {

            $password = md5($password);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";

                //if you want to redirect user as per its type, you can use this condition

                if('student' == $row['user_type']) {
                         header('Location: ogrenciarayuzu.php');
                         exit();
                } elseif ('department' == $row['user_type']) {
                             header('Location: bolumsekreterligiarayuzu.php');
                             exit();

                } elseif ('institute' == $row['user_type']) {
                             header('Location: enstituarayuzu.php');
                             exit();    

                } 
                else
                {
                    header('location: index.php');
                }
            }else {
                array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
            }
            }

         }
```

Comment: Also if you are calling `session_destroy()`. It will destroy all the session.

Comment: So no requirement of this code. `unset($_SESSION['username'])` .

Comment: Thanks your help and time. I appreciate that

Comment: I have another question. How can I display the full name? I added the name and username column into my database. I will log in with the username but  the page shows the name and surname of the that username.